# How to change default Python 2.7.10 to Python 3.6.2 on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-high-sierra

I would like to change the default python version to Python 3.6.2 on macOS instead of the default Python 2.7.10. So when I type 'python' in terminal, I want it to use Python 3.6.2. What will be a quick way to do this without installing Anaconda?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ which python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You can edit your `PATH` so that the python 3.6.2 directory is listed before the python 2.7.10 directory.

Comment: Thank you, Turry and John Gordon. Adding an alias for python in .bash_profile works.

 alias python='python3'